# Google App Engine Datastore: Extracting data using GQL query

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery

I'm currently playing with the Google App Engine datastore, and trying to extract some data from my applications database using GQL.

```
import os
import re
import random
import hashlib
import hmac
from string import letters

import webapp2
import jinja2

from google.appengine.ext import db

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape=True)

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)
    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)
    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class Users(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    password = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    email = db.EmailProperty(required = True)
    address = db.PostalAddressProperty(required = True)
    join_date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    dob = db.DateTimeProperty()
    phone = db.PhoneNumberProperty()

class MainPage(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("signup-form.html")
    def post(self):
        name = self.request.get("username")
        password = self.request.get("password")
        verify = self.request.get("verify")
        email = self.request.get("email")
        address = self.request.get("address")
        phone = self.request.get("phone")

        a = Users(name = name, password = password, email = email, address = address, phone = phone)
        a.put()
        p = Users.all()
        ans = p.filter("name = :1", "Manas")
        if(ans.email == "manas.oid@gmail.com"):
            self.response.write("Email found")
        else:
            self.response.write("Not found")


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

Now, there's already a 'Manas' attribute stored in my Users table, with 'manas.oid@gmail.com' as its corresponding email id. So, accordingly, I should get a 'Email found' message displayed. However, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Python 2.7\engineapp1\HelloApp\appapp\main.py", line 48, in post
    ans = p.filter("name = :1", "Manas")
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 2560, in filter
    prop = match.group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

What seems to be wrong with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Query.filter`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_filter) does not accept a placeholder.

Replace following line:

```
ans = p.filter("name = :1", "Manas")
```

with:

```
ans = p.filter("name =", "Manas")
```

**UPDATE**

`filter` returns an iterable, not a single record. You need to iterate it to check whether given email exist:

```
for x in ans:
    if x.email == "manas.oid@gmail.com":
        self.response.write("Email found")
else:
    self.response.write("Not found")
```

More preferably, using chained `Query.filter` and [`Query.count`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query_count), you don't need to iterate it.

```
ans = p.filter("name =", "Manas").filter("email =", "manas.oid@gmail.com")
if ans.count(limit=1):
    self.response.write("Email found")
else:
    self.response.write("Not found")
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'email'....this is the error I get now after replacing that line.

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi, That error is caused by next line. Because `filter` returns an iterable (`Query`) instead of single model instance. You need to iterate the result. I updated the answer. Check it out.